# Use item one by one from an array list in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am in trouble while parsing. I have an array list in Json format.

```
    {
      "details": [
        {
          "question_id": "1",
          "Questions": "QUESTION1",
          "Marks": "10"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "2",
          "Questions": "QUESTION2",
          "Marks": "10"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "3",
          "Questions": "QUESTION3",
          "Marks": "10"
        }
      ],
      "status_code": 1,
      "status_description": "Successsfull."
    }
```

Now from this JSONARRAY I need to send **question_id** from every object, to the next activity, where I need to send the **question_id** in the URL to get the next question from API.

My Question is how do I send the **question_id** one by one in another activity.
Actually this is a QUIZ APP.

Comment: I would suggest you look into Google Gson and pass the json as a stringExtra via intent. More info: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Sorry I don't get it right. You want to pass 1 id to the next activity or a list of ids? Anyway use putExtra on the intent of the new activity and retrieve it from bundle in the next activity.

Comment: Is it crucial to send it one by one? If not, you can easily pass the list as an extra. Otherwise, you have to provide an event in the second activity that when fired, asks the first activity for another item.

Comment: i can put and get it by  **i.getStringArrayListExtra("product_id")** but, i want to know how do i use it one by one to get my questions from JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class McqQuestionBeanCheck implements Serializable {

private int question_id;
private String questions,marks;


public int getQuestion_id() {
    return question_id;
}
public void setQuestion_id(int question_id) {
    this.question_id = question_id;
}
public String getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}
public void setQuestions(String questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}
public String getMarks() {
    return marks;
}
public void setMarks(String marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}

}
```

Use this method for Parsing...

```
    public ArrayList<McqQuestionBeanCheck> mcqQuestionParsingCheck(String response) {

    ArrayList<McqQuestionBeanCheck> questions = new ArrayList<McqQuestionBeanCheck>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray questionsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details");
        for (int i = 0; i < questionsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject questionObject = questionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            McqQuestionBeanCheck question = new McqQuestionBeanCheck();
            question.setQuestion_id(questionObject.getInt("question_id"));
            question.setQuestions(questionObject.getString("Questions"));
            question.setMarks(questionObject.getString("Marks"));

            questions.add(question);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return questions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of it fetch JSONArray using getJSONArray details and then fetch.Try like this to fetch.

```
 class Load_Filterad extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
    {

        String dis=filterdis.getText().toString();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        private static final String LOGIN_URL = "xxx";
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status_description";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "details";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("cat_id",finalcatid);
                params.put("district",dis);

                Log.d("request", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());
                    result = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            if (json != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    filterdis.setText("");
                    result=json.getString("result");
                    if(result.equals("true"))
                    {

                        browseadarray=json.getJSONArray("product_result");
                        for (int i = 0; i < browseadarray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject c = browseadarray.optJSONObject(i);
                            if (c != null)
                            {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                String advertise_id = c.getString("advertise_id");
                                String add_title = c.getString("add_title");
                                String cat_id = c.getString("cat_id");
                                String subcat_id = c.getString("subcat_id");
                                String add_price = c.getString("add_price");
                                String add_description = c.getString("add_description");
                                String add_name = c.getString("add_name");
                                String add_phone = c.getString("add_phone");
                                String add_city = c.getString("add_city");
                               // String add_district = c.getString("add_district");
                               // String add_taluka = c.getString("add_taluka");
                                String image_1 = c.getString("image_name");



                                map.put("advertise_id", advertise_id);
                                map.put("add_title", add_title);
                                map.put("cat_id", cat_id);
                                map.put("subcat_id", subcat_id);
                                map.put("add_price", add_price);
                                map.put("add_description", add_description);
                                map.put("add_name", add_name);
                                map.put("add_phone", add_phone);
                                map.put("add_city", add_city);
                                //map.put("add_district", add_district);
                                //map.put("add_taluka", add_taluka);
                                map.put("image_1", image_1);


                                arraylist_browsead.add(map);
                                System.out.println(arraylist_browsead);

                            }

                        }
                        browseAdvertiseAdapter = new BrowseAdvertiseAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist_browsead);
                        browseadlist.setAdapter(browseAdvertiseAdapter);
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Product Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Advertise Available...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should **parse the Json** to an object (U can build a related POJO class in ur project,then use google Gson api). And then put all the **id** in a list by looping through the **details** list.And then pass the id list to the next activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

first parse the json format like below:

```
String json = YOUR_JSON_TEXT;

// fetch details array in json data.
JSONArray json_array = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("details");

// make an array to save question id's,
int all_question_id[] = new int[json_array.length()];

// read question id's from json_array
for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
    all_question_id[i] = json_array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("question_id");
}

// pass all of them, which are separated to destionation activity
Intent questions = new Intent();
questions.putExtra("ALL_QUESTION_ID", all_question_id);
startActivity(questions);
```

now all you need is `getExtras` in the destination activity, like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

int question_id[] = null;

if(extras!=null){
    question_id = extras.getIntArray("ALL_QUESTION_ID");
}
```